# Firebase: how to handle two PWA apps in the same project?

Tags: firebase, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I'm developing a project where I need two PWA apps defined on the same Firebase project, sharing the same database. One of this app is the 'producer' and the other one is the 'consumer' of the data.
So far I developed the 'producer' side and everything is ok - it writes in the database. Now I'm starting with the 'consumer' side.
Defined like now I'm not able to deploy the second one, cause it shares the same hosting so it overwrites the first app.

How can I structure the project to have two PWA apps sharing the same DB but not the same hosting (and URL)?

Comment: In addition to Michael's answer, I would add that you can very well deploy a PWA in one Firebase project (using the hosting service) that interacts with the database of another Firebase Project. You just have to configure Firebase in the PWA with the config of the second project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to [create a second Firebase Hosting site](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9095420?hl=en) in the project, which you can then deploy to separately.